# Wiring in fixture looks wrong and I need a fix

Tags: ceiling, light-fixture

[image: ceiling fixture with bad connections]

So I opened this up to see about putting a fan in but it really looks odd to me. On the left are three black wires connected together. In the middle two white wires with the white of the light and then a white wire is connected to the black of the light. The light had been working fine but one of my bathroom lights had been acting weird ever since we moved in. It basically stays on at all times whether the switch is in on position or off. If the bedroom wiring is incorrect how should I fix it?

Comment: Is there another light also controlled by that same switch?   Are there indeed only 3 blacks on the nut, 2 from the ceiling and 1 from the lamp?

Comment: There are 3 black from the ceiling spliced together. There is one white from the ceiling spliced with the black from the light. There are two white from the ceiling spliced to the white from the light.

Comment: What do you see when you open the switch?  Is it possibly just a black wire on the hot side and a white wire on the switched side?